# How to figure out who made the mistake

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Two biologists at a certain company are responsible for analyzing water samples.
Biologist 1 analyzes 45% of all water samples while biologist 2 analyzes 55%. Biologist
one makes a mistake 3% of the time while biologist 2 makes a mistake 1% of the time.
If a particular water sample was analyzed incorrectly, what is the probability that it was
biologist 1 who analyzed it?

Comment: What did you do first? Walk us through it.

Comment: I don't even really know how to start it , I tried to find the probability they each make mistakes which was P(B1 makes mistake)= 0.0135 and P(B2 makes mistake)=0.0055  but I'm not sure if that's what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Try to avoid simply posting a problem. Rather explain which parts you don't understand, what you have tried, how you know you are wrong etc.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to set out the information in the form of a tree:

```
                         +-(0.03)-: (A) Mistake     (0.0135)
 +-(0.45)-: Biologist 1 -|
 |                       +-(0.97)-: (B) No mistake  (0.4365)
-|
 |                       +-(0.01)-: (C) Mistake     (0.0055)
 +-(0.55)-: Biologist 2 -|
                         +-(0.99)-: (D) No mistake  (0.5445)
```

The probabilities given in the parentheses on the right correspond to all the possible outcomes without knowing which of the two biologists performed the water analysis or whether there was a mistake made.

If we know that *a mistake has been made* then notice that events (B) and (D) are ruled out. The probability that remains given this information, then, is then 0.0135 + 0.0055 (events A + C), of which only 0.0135 (event C) represents the probability that it was biologist 1 that made the mistake. The probability that biologist 1 made the mistake, then, is:

$$\frac{0.0135}{0.0135 + 0.0055}=0.71$$

See [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) for more on "reversing the condition" type problems.